# Getting schema fields for particular schema version

Tags: core-service, schema

I need to get schema data and schema fields for particular version of schema.

To get schema data I use the next code

```
SchemaData schema = (SchemaData)Client.Read(schemaUri, null);
```

(schemaUri == "tcm:6166-36918-8-v1")

This code returns data for specified version. I can see this from schema.Xsd property in debug

To get schema fields I use the next code

```
SchemaFieldsData schemaFieldsData = Client.ReadSchemaFields(schemaUri, false, null);
```

(schemaUri == "tcm:6166-36918-8-v1")

Unfortunately this code returns the latest version ("tcm:6166-36918-8")

I can see this in debug as well

How can I return fields for particular version?

- parse XSD?
- save schema data to temp schema and then get fields from temp schema?
- any normal way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to temporally roll forward the schema to the current version so that you can use `SchemaFieldsData`, then when you've finished delete the version.

That said, it's certainly much safer to work with the XSD information.